# Is there a checkbox-like button in WinRT-XAML

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Is there a checkbox-like button in WinRT-XAML?

What I mean, is there a button with an IsPressed (or equiv) property that will remain pressed after the user taps it? Then "unselects" after the user taps it again?

Comment: BTW, thanks for StorageHelper @JerryNixon

Comment: Here's the storagehelper http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ToggleSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch.aspx) is what you're looking for

[image: ToggleSwitch]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its called "Toggle Button" or "Toggle Switch".
For more details refer MSDN : [WinRT control List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx)